# swift - using replaceRange() to change certain occurrences in a string

Tags: ios, xcode, string, swift

Say I have a string, and I want to change the first "a" in that string to an "e" in order to get the correct spelling.

```
let animal = "elaphant"
```

Using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString()` will change every "a" in that string to an "e", returning:

```
elephent
```

I am trying to get the index of the first "a" and then replacing it using `replaceRange()`, like so:

```
let index = animal.characters.indexOf("a")
let nextIndex = animal.startIndex.distanceTo(index!)
animal = animal.replaceRange(animal.startIndex.advancedBy(nextIndex)..<animal.startIndex.advancedBy(1), with: "e")
```

However, this code gives me the following error:

```
Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String'
```

I have been trying to find a way to convert nextIndex into an `Int`, but I feel like I've got this whole method wrong. Help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is is what you want to do:

```
var animal = "elaphant"
if let range = animal.rangeOfString("a") {
  animal.replaceRange(range, with: "e")
}
```

`rangeOfString` will search for the first occurrence of the provided substring and if that substring can be found it will return a optional range otherwise it will return nil.

we need to unwrap the optional and the safest way is with an `if let` statement so we assign our range to the constant `range`.

The `replaceRange` will do as it suggests, in this case we need `animal` to be a `var`.

Comment: Wow, guess I was overthinking it. What if I wanted to change the second "a" to an "e" instead of the first one?

Comment: @wasimsandhu the `rangeOfString` function has a default parameter called options, you can use `animal.rangeOfString("a", options: .BackwardsSearch)` to find the first match coming from the end of the string.

Comment: @LeoDabus has provided a much more flexible answer on that question i would recommend taking a look at that. As this answer on really helps for the first and last occurrence of the letter "a".

Comment: `replaceRange` is now `replaceSubrange` in Swift 3

Answer (score 5):

update:

**Swift 4.2 or later**

```
var animal = "elaphant"
if let index = animal.firstIndex(of: "a") {
    animal.replaceSubrange(index...index, with: ["e"])
}
```

---

We can extend `RangeReplaceableCollection` Protocol and create our own `replaceFirstOccurrence(of: Element)` method:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func replaceFirstOccurrence(of element: Element, with replacement: Element) {
        guard let index = firstIndex(of: element) else { return }
        replaceSubrange(index...index, with: CollectionOfOne(replacement))
    }
    func replacingFirstOccurrence(of element: Element, with replacement: Element) -> Self {
        var elements = self
        elements.replaceFirstOccurrence(of: element, with: replacement)
        return elements
    }
}
```

---

```
var animal = "elaphant"

// non mutating method
print(animal.replacingFirstOccurrence(of: "a", with: "e"))  // elephant
print(animal)     // still "elaphant"

// mutating method
animal.replaceFirstOccurrence(of: "a", with: "e")
print(animal)    // mutated to "elephant"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Playground:

```
var animal = "elaphant"
if let range = animal.rangeOfString("a") {
animal.replaceRange(range, with: "e")
}

print (animal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift4

```
var animal = "elaphant"

if let index = animal.index(of: "a") {
    animal.replaceSubrange(index...index, with: "e")
}

print (animal) // elephant
```