# Replace occurrences in String

Tags: swift

I want to replace the first occurrence in a String and the second.

I have not tried anything yet

ex:

```
var mString = "my car is black, my phone is black"
```

I want to replace the first black to blue and the second black to red

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416484-replacingoccurrences

This should be what to use, but literally the first rule of StackOverflow is to try code, or just google what you're trying to do before asking.

Comment: Oh I thought you can use `NSRange` to specify a specific range in string. Such as have from initial to `,`, and `,` to end.

Comment: Can you specify `NSMakeRange(_:_:)` on the `NSRange` parameter? I don't program in `swift` but just looking at it from a documentation perspective.

Comment: @RileyCarney You are discouraged from using `NSRange` with Swift `String`.

Comment: Oh my bad then :p, just thinking of how I would work it from a programming perspective. Is this question already asked on stackoverflow here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085076/swift-using-replacerange-to-change-certain-occurrences-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array with the new strings. Find the range of first matching substring "black" in the string using [`range(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410144-range). And replace with the new string in the range using [`replaceSubrange(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126958-replacesubrange) method.
Then continue the loop till last element of the array.

```
var mString = "my car is black, my phone is black"
["blue","red"].forEach {
    if let range = mString.range(of: "black") {
        mString.replaceSubrange(range, with: $0)
    }
}
print(mString)
```

> my car is blue, my phone is red

Check [Swift String Cheat Sheet](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-string-cheat-sheet/)